# How to loop a Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I m programming a 2d game in which i want to animate a torch that lights on and off. I have one animation for the torch turned on and one for the torch turned off. It should be on for 3 seconds and off for other 3 seconds in a infinite loop.
this is the code:

```
Animator anim;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    StartCoroutine(waitSeconds());
}  

IEnumerator waitSeconds()
{  
    while(true)
    {
        anim.Play("firetorchon-Animation");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        anim.Play("firetorchoff-Animation");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
}
```

the while loop doesn t work - only the turned off animation is shown and it never transitions to turned on, how can i achieve this in another way?

Comment: well, i was gonna correct your formatting but as you pasted it without any.. im not going to format your code properly.. So.. if you call the waitseconds coroutine as you have which appears to have while true in it.. it should being doing what you thought however, you havent explained what it does do so.. who knows. nothing wrong there.

Comment: In which sense "you havent explained what it does"? What i forgot to specify?

Comment: well the code above will run, and will forever play the on then off animation.. so.. you forgot to point out how this isnt working.. and what actually happens

Comment: Ah yes sorry, it happens that only the turned off animation is shown and it never transitions to turned on

Comment: Well the code doesnt back that up. So why not. You need to debug it

Comment: The code looks fine, so if the 'firetorchon' animation is not playing either a) that's not the correct string name, b) there's some condition preventing it from playing or c) in the animation graph it's not wired up to e.g. entry or other states to allow it to play or d) there's something wrong with the animation itself (does it play in the inspector?) or e) it's not configured to play for 3 seconds e.g. it's not set to loop or the end time is too short

Answer (score 0):

Anyway there is a much easier way to achieve the same thing without using code, you just have to set "exit time" in the Animator panel putting the number of seconds you want the animation to last.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is use `InvokeRepeating()` to call a function that calls the coroutine. This probably isn't the best way, but it's the easiest and fastest.

```cs
Animator anim;

private void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(AnimateTorch), 0f, 0f);
}

private void AnimateTorch()
{
    StartCoroutine(waitSeconds());
}

IEnumerator waitSeconds()
{
    anim.Play("firetorchon-Animation");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    anim.Play("firetorchoff-Animation");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
}
```

If the code doesn't work, then you may need to make sure that the animation is done correctly.